# Most direct way of getting from Malaga airport to Granada?

Tags: spain, malaga

I want to know the best options for getting from Malaga airport to Granada. I don't want to hire a car, so maybe I could travel by bus or taxi? And ideas how much this could cost? I don't want to get ripped off!

Answer (score 4):

Málaga is the closest international airport to Granada and there are many flights. Málaga airport is 125km from Granada and it takes about 90 minutes to drive from Malaga to Granada.

**GETTING FROM MÁLAGA BY BUS**

It is best to use public transport to get to Granada. The bus is faster than the train. Buses leave from Málaga bus station and arrive at Granada bus station. The journey takes between 90 minutes (11.43€) and 120 minutes (13.72€). The price of a return ticket is double the price of a one-way ticket so there is no saving in buying a return.

There are direct buses from Málaga airport to Granada bus station. The journey takes 2 hours 15/30 minutes and a one-way ticket costs 11.43€/13.72€.

BUS TIMES:

*MÁLAGA (AIRPORT) - GRANADA (BUS STATION):* 08:30, 10:45, 11:00, 11:30, 16:00, 18:30 and 20:45

If you arrive at the airport and no bus is leaving shortly, you’d better reach Malaga bus station.

*MÁLAGA (AIRPORT) - MÁLAGA (BUS STATION):* 06:25 - 23:30 (EVERY 30 MINUTES)

From here, more frequent and more economic journeys leave for Granada. The prices range from € 7, 25 to € 13, 70, depending on the time you leave and service you choose.

*MÁLAGA (BUS STATION) - GRANADA (BUS STATION):* 
07:00, 08:00, 09:00, 10:00, 11:15, 11:30, 12:00, 13:00, 14:00, 15:00, 16:00, 16:30, 17:00, 18:30, 19:00, 20:00, 21:15, 21:30

You can purchase bus tickets & get further info from [here](https://www.alsa.es/en/)

**Getting from Málaga airport in a taxi**

Just go to the taxi rank at the airport and try to get the best price. You should be able to get the price down to 140 or even lower. You will need to show them the address of where you are going and then ask the price. It is a good idea to get them to write the figure down on a paper so that they can't later say it was higher and that you didn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Always check trip advisor for reliable & trustworthy companies first.
Also we had a right problem when we did not book but had to wait at the airport in Malaga for a taxi and the local taxi chaps were moaning at all of our luggage.
Have you tried [www.solhop.com](http://solhop.com/)? They were really helpful with questions about all of our extra luggage and they contacted the driver to make sure he was waiting when we were running late. You will have to ask them directly for a quote, but you don't have to pay anything until they pick you up anyway.

Comment: I would check out more than just one internet review site.